# Synonym for personal offense

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I feel that the word personal offense is too harsh. I'm trying to find a word or phrase (preferably a word) that means offensive but more hurt. Like provoking feelings of sadness instead of anger. Like attack or assault but to a much much lower degree.

- Her words were a _______ to my already bruised ego, making me feel worse.
- His kind offer to show me around was a _______ to my belief that I was good at finding my way around.

Answer (score 3):

One word that seems to fit is **affront**: "a contemptuous treatment; an open insult; indignity"

> [[Chambers](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=affront&title=21st)] **affront** noun, an insult, especially one delivered in public. verb (affronted, affronting) 1 to insult someone, especially in public. 2 to offend the pride of someone; to embarrass.
> ETYMOLOGY: 14c: from French *affronter*, to slap in the face.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the words / offer to be a metaphorical punch or hit. The term *blow* suggests this metaphor while conveying mainly the sense of hurt rather than attack.

> **blow** (2nd set) *noun*
> 1.1 A sudden shock or disappointment.
> ‘the news came as a crushing blow to the cast’
> ‘He was dealt a disappointing blow here yesterday when the group failed to justify hefty support.’
> [- Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/blow)

Your examples would then look like:

- Her words were a **blow** to my already bruised ego, making me feel worse.
- His kind offer to show me around was a **blow** to my belief that I was good at finding my way around.

Answer (score 0):

**A disgruntling remark** is a remark that makes the person concerned discontented, that puts them into sulky humour.

> (SOED) **disgruntle** Make discontented; put into a sulky humour. Chiefly as *disgruntled* ppl a.
> **disgruntlement** n. moody discontent

In order to use the noun some modifications are necessary.

- Her words caused  to my already bruised ego some  disgruntlement, making me feel worse.

The word "**wound**" carries more of the idea of an offense.

- Her words were a wound to my aready bruised ego, making me feel worse.

> ([OAlD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/wound1_1?q=wound)) mental or emotional pain caused by something unpleasant that has been said or done to you

Answer (score 0):

How about **slight**? From Lexico:

> **[slight](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/slight)**: An insult caused by a failure to show someone proper respect or attention; ‘an unintended slight can create grudges’

Your examples:

> Her words were a **slight** to my already bruised ego, making me feel worse.

> His kind offer to show me around was a **slight** to my belief that I was good at finding my way around.

**Slight** is certainly less harsh than *attack* or *assault*. It seems less harsh than *personal offense* and could be made more so if you used the phrase **unintended slight**. From the definition above, it's also clear that **slight** conveys a *personal offense*, i.e., a lack of due respect or attention.

Answer (score -1):

In the sentences provided, the most idiomatic choice I can think of is **blow**:

> an unexpected event that has a damaging effect on someone or something — [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/blow)

The article [8 Ways to Overcome a Blow to Your Ego](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/fulfillment-any-age/201609/8-ways-overcome-blow-your-ego), for example, has not doing well in a 5k and not being picked for a team at work as examples of events that may be a blow to one’s ego. This shows that the connotation of *blow* is not quite so harsh as being offended (though it can be intensified as Cambridge shows: “Her death came as a terrible blow to her parents.”).